# How should I read specific data for the specific user from database by python django

Tags: python, django

For example, in my database, I have a table called BlackList which looks like this:
[image]

The models of the table is:

```
class BlackList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    flag1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    flag2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')  # Get username input first
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    # BLname = Read the username from the table
    # BLflag1 = read the Flag1 for the user
    # BLflag2 = read the Flag2 for the user
    if BLflag1 == True and BLflag2 == True:  
        something will happen 
    elif BLflag1 == True and BLflag2 == False:  
        something will happen
    else:
        # set the Flag1 and Flag2 of this user to True.
```

So, my questions are

1. How to read the specific data for a specific user, for example, if the User 'aaa' try to log in, the application will read Flag1 for aaa is True and Flag2 for aaa is True.
2. How to set the Flag for a specific user, for example, if user 'bbb' try to log in, the application will set Flag1 and Flag2 into True in the end.

Comment: `if user.username=="aaa":`
`BLflag1 = True`
`BLflag2 == True`

Comment: `if user.username=="bbb": `
`BLflag2 = True `
`BLflag2 == True`

Comment: Please add the model you use for the table image you added.

Comment: @Vincent OK, I add the model.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if the user is authenticated.

```py
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    BLname = user.username
    BLflag1 = user.Flag1
    BLflag2 = user.Flag2
    if BLflag1 and BLflag2:  # since the values are boolean, you don't need to compare them  
        # something will happen 
    elif BLflag1 and not BLflag2:  
        # something will happen
    else:
        user.Flag1 = True
        user.Flag2 = True
        user.save()
else:
    # do something for unauthenticated users
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes, I had all others parts such as check authenticated, if the model for the table called 'class BlackList(models.Model)...', will the user.Flag1 and user.Flag2 work? Because I do not feel it read data from the database.

Comment: In case you want to read from a `BlackList` model, you should use `black_list_user = BlackList.objects.get(username=user.username)` (I recommend wrapping this in a try except in case the user is not blacklisted) and then use `black_list_user.Flag1` and `black_list_user.Flag2`.

Comment: When I try `black_list_user = BlackList.objects.get(username=user.username)` it shows an `error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'`, but it can read by `black_list_user = BlackList.objects.get(username=user.username)`, the other problem is `black_list_user.Flag2` can only use for read, when I am doing `black_list_user.Flag2=True`, the data cannot be saved or go to the database for some reasons.

Comment: Ops, just I forget the `user.save()`, Thanks a lot, lol

Comment: Did you write the `black_list_user` inside the `if user is not None` condition? Unless you don't want to use `authenticate`, in that case just do `black_list_user = BlackList.objects.get(username=username)`